# Automatically assign tasks to other users when importing from Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-outlook, csv

I am trying to automatically assign tasks imported from an Excel spreadsheet to other users. The problem I'm facing is that tasks that I import from a CSV are created for me, and I then have to manually assign each task individually in Outlook to other users. Is there a way to use the users' names or email addresses in the spreadsheet to assign these tasks as part of the import process?

Comment: Outlook doesn't have a built-in option to realize this. I recommend you post this idea to Outlook UserVoice:  https://outlook.uservoice.com/

Answer (score 0):

You could use a VBA macro to create the tasks as described in this [Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35689891/1414000).